# Is there a difference between porting and migration in programming?

Tags: language-agnostic, embedded

Is there a general difference or in the context of embedded systems programming ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These aren't formal terms, so this is quite a bit subjective.

Migration means moving your code base to another system (without the intention of going back). It could also mean switching to another tool chain or programming language.

Porting is a broader term - it means adapting code to a specific system. Migration is a form of porting. But porting could also mean making support for multiple systems. A "port" is a certain system-specific version of a multi-system code base.

Comment: Late comment but, "porting" relates or might be (and usually is related) to "portable". What means code meant or designed to run in multiple platforms.